# Load the class dynamically and get the annotated classes

Tags: java, class, methods, reflection

```
import com.this.class.Factory;
      public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        // Itearate over all @Factory annotated elements
        for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Factory.class)) {
            ...
        }
      }
```

This  works when I import the annotation class in the annotation processor. But when the annotation class is loaded dynamically doesn't works

```
Class<?> Factorry = class.forName("com.this.class.Factory")
 public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        // Itearate over all @Factory annotated elements
        for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Factory.class)) {
            ...
        }
      }
```

How to pass the annotated Factory.class to getElementsAnnotatedWith when the class is loaded  using class.forName()

Comment: Please provide more information concerning "doesn't works"

Comment: Factory cannot be resolved to a type. This is the compilation error I see. It is looking for the Factory.class file import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change two things:

1. Factorry variable should be cast as an Annotation:

   `Class<Annotation> Factorry = (Class<Annotation>)class.forName("com.this.class.Factory")`
2. Use Factorry variable instead of Factory.class:

   `roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Factorry)`

Comment: Factory factory= method.getAnnotation(Factory);

will this work in the same scenario?

Comment: I can't answer since I don't know what is Factory and method? Maybe you should post another question with more detail.

Comment: Here is the question I'm looking for 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662984/run-time-annotation-scanning-when-dynamic-class-loading