# run time annotation scanning when Dynamic class loading

Tags: java, class, methods, reflection, annotation-processing

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

// declare a new annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Demo {
   String str();
   int val();
}

public class PackageDemo {

   // set values for the annotation
   @Demo(str = "Demo Annotation", val = 100)
   // a method to call in the main
   public static void example() {
      PackageDemo ob = new PackageDemo();

      try {
         Class c = ob.getClass();

         // get the method example
         Method m = c.getMethod("example");

         // get the annotation for class Demo
         Demo annotation = m.getAnnotation(Demo.class);

         // print the annotation
         System.out.println(annotation.str() + " " + annotation.val());
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
         exc.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      example();
   }
}
```

My objective is to check the annotation on few methods and if it exists on the annotation , I need to get the annotation.

```
Demo annotation = m.getAnnotation(Demo.class);
```

In the above example , the annotation is declared in the same file. If annotation is in a different package I can do something like

```
import com.this.class.DemoClass
try {
         Class c = ob.getClass();

         // get the method example
         Method m = c.getMethod("example");

         // get the annotation for class Demo
         Demo annotation = m.getAnnotation(Demo.class);
```

But if I want to load the DemoClass/AnnotationClass dynamically like

```
Class<?> Demo = Class.forName("com.this.class.DemoClass")
```

How do I get the annotation on the methods. I think the below line doesn't works in this case

```
Demo annotation = m.getAnnotation(Demo.class);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish? Try to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @fragmentedreality updated the question let me know if you still need some information.

Comment: I suggest, that you adjust the title of your question: term "annotation processor" has [specific meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/annotation-processing/info) in scope of Java language. The term, that would be more suitable for your goals is *runtime annotation scanning* or simply [introspection](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/introspection/info).

Comment: @user1643723 updated the title.

Comment: I didn't look into specifics of your question, but have you tried to use one of existing libraries for your task? [fast-classpath-scanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner) or one of it's alternatives would make your work a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach worked for me. hope this helps someone.

```
 DemoClass= (Class<Annotation>) Class.forName("com.this.class.DemoClass");
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(DemoClass)) {
       for (Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations()) {
       Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType = annotation.annotationType();      
       if (annotationType.getName() == "com.this.class.DemoClass") {
          for (Method annotationMethod : annotationType.getDeclaredMethods()) {
          value= annotationMethod.invoke(annotation, (Object[]) null);
          }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the annotation is loaded dynamically into variable, `Demo`, then use that variable to get the annotation:

```
Class<?> Demo = Class.forName("com.this.class.DemoClass");
Demo annotation = m.getAnnotation(Demo);
```

Comment: Tried. I have encountered 2 issues here. 1st one is Demo  cannot be resolved to a type and then The method getAnnotation(Class<T>) in the type Method is not applicable for the arguments.

Comment: I agree with fragmentedreality. WIth a minimal, complete and verifiable example, we can then recommend fixes.

Comment: what you said first is what I'm trying to accomplish. But the approach is not working as I said. The requirement is clear. Not sure what you are not understanding in it. 
I'm trying to get the annotation of a particular annotation class  like 
Demo annotation = m.getAnnotation(Demo); 
It works  when I use import to load the Demo class .
But not sure how to do the same operation when Demo.class is loaded using Class.forname()